# how to set up a method to be always called the first time when it enters a class

Tags: soql, apex

I need to add a method to cleanup a table (a custom object in SF) before any other methods in that class are called.
I tried calling that method in the class's constructor,and later realized that I am not instantiating it.
I then did instantiate the class,but when observed the logs,there seems to be a FATAL_ERROR due to too many SOQL queries? not sure why?
Is there any way like TestNg,that I can have that method being called always at the start?
Can I set up a trigger?
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks and Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a "static" method block, but be aware that it will run once per transaction any time that class is touched in any way (via static methods, constructors, etc). It looks like this:

```
public class X {
    static {
        // Do your logic here
    }
}
```

It will be called before any static methods, constructors, etc are called.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox. Thank you for the reply.This will work,even though I have a static method that I want to call? I have the delete logic inside a static method.

Comment: Static blocks work everywhere, so I don't see why this shouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

As a possible solution you can use an **action** attribute of the **apex:page** tag:

```
<apex:page action="{!yourMethod}"
```

Here is description:

> The action method invoked when this page is requested by the server.
>   Use expression language to reference an action method. For example,
>   action="{!doAction}" references the doAction() method in the
>   controller. If an action is not specified, the page loads as usual. If
>   the action method returns null, the page simply refreshes. This method
>   will be called before the page is rendered and allows you to
>   optionally redirect the user to another page. This action should not
>   be used for initialization.

Comment: Thank you @mast0r,but I don't think I am using any apex pages. But,will figure out in a while.